# Android: Inflating a specific section of an xml file

Tags: android

I wish to inflate the code below (taken from list_item_icon_text.xml of the android api demos).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Unfortunately, in the demo, the inflation was done using

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text, null);
```

in list14.java.

I would like to include the above code in **my own xml file and only inflate this LinearLayout**, but I have been searching online and trying to do this for hours. I'm really frustrated at this point. I managed to inflate the whole xml file, which is not what I wanted. I only want to inflate this particular section (having added it to my xml file). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to save your file in your `layout` folder, let say 'my_layout.xml` and when inflating you'll use your id :

```
     inflate(R.layout.my_layout);
```

Be sure that the right imports are made. I mean importing your `R.java` file by using :

```
     import my.packaage.com.R;
```

Comment: i dont want to inflate my whole layout. only the code above which i added to my file.

Comment: a better question is: can i inflate a LinearLayout using its android:id?